# Website Login Issue developed in magento

Tags: magento

I have a website developed using magento . Previously i was able to login. But right now, login is failed. Infact any operations that interacts with user table is failing. I need to know what is the issue. How do I figure it out?

Comment: have you check the system log ?

Comment: yes nothing is there

Comment: you mean in system.log of magento  and are you sure that log is enable from magento admin

Comment: @yshooooo Have you upgraded Magento? Or migrated  it to a different server?

Answer (score 0):

First clear try to clear your log file

second make sure you have not upgraded your Magento

and 3rd make sure that you db is accessible in your Magento

-Harry P